# How do I convert a unicode text to a text that python can read so that I could find that specific word in webscraping results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-re, python-unicode

I am trying to scrape text in instagram and check if I could find some keywords in the bio but the user use a special fonts, so I cannot identify the specific word, how can I remove the fonts or formot of a text such that I can search the word?

```
import re
test="      . "


x = re.findall(re.compile('past'), test)
if x:    
    print("TEXT FOUND")
else:
    print("TEXT NOT FOUND")
```

> TEXT NOT FOUND

Another example:

```
import re
test="ғʀᴇᴇʟᴀɴᴄᴇ ɢʀᴀᴘʜɪᴄ ᴅᴇsɪɢɴᴇʀ"
test=test.lower()

x = re.findall(re.compile('graphic'), test)
if x:    
    print("TEXT FOUND")
else:
    print("TEXT NOT FOUND")
```

> TEXT NOT FOUND

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) that Return the normal form for the Unicode string. For your examples see the following code snippet:

```py
import re
import unicodedata

test="      . "
 
formatted_test = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', test).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')

x = re.findall(re.compile('past'), formatted_test)
if x:    
    print("TEXT FOUND")
else:
    print("TEXT NOT FOUND")
```

and the output will be:

> TEXT FOUND

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:**

Take care if you are dealing with texts in Portuguese.
If you have:

```
string = """ orçamento"""
```

And you use:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', string).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

You will lost cedilha (ç), it means, ***orçamento*** will be ***orcamento***.

Otherwise, if you use:

```
unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', string)
```

You will keep cedilha.

Note that I changed **NFKD** to **NFKC**, beyond cut encode and decode.

**Problem 2:**

Take this examples (they are real examples that I found in Instagram):

```
    string2 = """ᴍᴇᴜ ᴄᴏʀᴀçãᴏ ᴀᴛé ᴘᴜʟᴏᴜ ǫᴜᴀɴᴅᴏ ᴇʟᴀ ᴘᴀssᴏᴜ, ᴍᴀs ᴏ ǫᴜᴇ ғᴇᴢ ᴇʟᴇ ᴘᴀʀᴀʀ ғᴏɪ sᴇᴜ ᴀʙʀᴀçᴏ"""
    string3 = """"""
    string4 = """(n̶ã̶o̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶á̶g̶u̶a̶ ̶d̶o̶c̶e̶!̶)"""
```

The lib Unicodedata is not able to normalize them.

Note that, string2 looks like "normal", but it is write using LATIN LETTER SMALL instead LATIN, besides the letter F is not an F, it is CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER GHE WITH STROKE.

One alternative is Unidecode https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/

```
print(unidecode(string2)) 
MEU CORAcaO ATe PULOU oUAnDO ELA PAssOU, MAs O oUE g'EZ ELE PARAR g'OI sEU ABRAcO

print(unidecode(string3))
(C)(U)(I)(D)(A)(D)(O)

print(unidecode(string4))
nao use agua doce!
```

But Unidecode will normalize everything to ASCII, so we will back to the problem 1.